# Database connect undefined

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting an error saying **Undefined variable: con**,

the connection of the database is on the other php file, (include() is already on top of the code). I just don't know how to call the $con

```
if (isset($_POST['update_profile'])) 
{
    if (isset($_POST['first_name']))
    {
        $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbl_fbusers SET fname = '$first_name' WHERE email = '$email_to_connect'");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['last_name']))
    {
        $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbl_fbusers SET lname = '$last_name' WHERE email = '$email_to_connect'");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['contact']))
    {
        $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact']);
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbl_fbusers SET contact = '$contact' WHERE email = '$email_to_connect'");
    }
}
```

here is the other php file

```
class Users {
    public $table_name = 'tbl_fbusers';

    function __construct(){
        //database configuration
        $dbServer = 'localhost'; //Define database server host
        $dbUsername = 'root'; //Define database username
        $dbPassword = ''; //Define database password
        $dbName = 'db_zalian'; //Define database name

        //connect databse
        $con = mysqli_connect($dbServer,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }else{
            $this->connect = $con;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can not just call a variable inside a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a class you need to initialize user class.

```
$user = new Users();
```

and then

```
$con = $user->connect;
```

Here you can run your sql like:

```
$contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact']);
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbl_fbusers SET contact =......... etc.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It shows no more errors, but my database is not updating base on the query I stated. Where could be the problem?

Comment: I have test the method and it works, the only problem I could think of you have many if statements, try to call update method just to see if any thing get updated and then work backword, because you have if statement, and post method, so try to make it in small peases

Comment: are you working on the same file or different files?

Comment: I'm working with different files, maybe I could place the query inside a function in the class. I will also try your suggestion .

Comment: my point is before doing a lot of stuff at once, try to make simple tests by updating a single value too see things works than expand your work step by step, otherwise it will be fire fighting good luck

Answer (score 1):

Defining `$con` as a `GLOBAL variable` is a terrible idea...

I suggest to make a file (eg. `connection.php`) that will contain the `$con` variable that is not in a function, and then include the `connection.php` to your other php files. It's more secure and easier, and you won't get to any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define $con as global:

```
global $con
$con = mysqli_connect($dbServer,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
```

Comment: then how do I call it?

Comment: @CarlNabongCaraig when you instantiate a Users class, the variable $con will be initialized. something like $users = new Users()